# Get exif from file without Image class

Tags: c#, image, exif

I am trying to get the jpg preview from a DNG file (not the thumbnail). From what I can tell, the preview is simply an exif preview, not specific to DNG. However as much googling as I do, I can't find anything about specifically getting the preview from the exif of a file in c#.

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html

From this site it appears that the preview starts at Tag ID 0x0111, Group SubIFD1 for DNG. The length is at 0x0117, SubIFD1. But I don't really understand what the group means. I have used the Image.GetPropertyItem() before but I think that because the file is a DNG, it won't let me load it as an Image, I get an out of memory exception which apparently can mean that it's an unrecognized pixel format.

**Is the image format integral to the exif information, or is there a way to read it without needing to decode the DNG?**

I am aware that there are libraries made for opening DNG, but so far I have been unsuccessful in adapting these to my software and I would like to keep it fast and light. If I can just pluck this preview out it would really be a perfect situation.

Answer (score 0):

The DNG specification is an extension of TIFF, so if you have a TIFF decoder that supports JPEG compression, it should be able to decode the preview image (the preview is JPEG decoded). You might need to "help" pointing the decoder to the correct sub-IFD, though.

Otherwise, you could parse the TIFF structure, find the correct IFD, and use a JPEG decoder to decode the embedded JPEG preview.

I have created a [reader in Java](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/camera-raw/imageio/imageio-dng/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/plugins/dng/DNGImageReader.java) (still work in progress), that parses the TIFF structure and extracts the thumbnail (if present) and preview (and some lame attempts to extract the uncompressed RAW CFA data, which is far from done). Although the code isn't production quality yet, it might give you some inspiration.

Good luck! :-)